# Code snippet plugin for windows live writer

Tags: windows, wordpress

Do you know of any Windows live writer plugins which formats code (php, html, css, js) in a good way?
I've already tried:

- [Insert Code](http://insertcode.codeplex.com/)
- [Code snippet](http://plugins.live.com/writer/detail/code-snippet-plugin-for-windows-live-writer)

But they do not have what I want. First, they put up scrolls whenever the code that I input is long like this:
[image]

I want something like this, from net tuts:
[image]

How do I achieve that? Are the styles applied in here dependent to my current wordpress theme.

Comment: Well, what's your WP theme?

Comment: I'm using zbench theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This one](http://richhewlett.com/2010/02/02/new-version-of-source-code-syntax-highlighting-live-writer-plugin-for-wordpress-com-blogs/) seems to lack WYSIWYG but lets you style the code with your WP theme instead of in the plugin settings.